# Dynamically modify content_scripts.matches in FireFox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, content-script, firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

So I'm trying to follow the instructions for a firefox extension using WebExtensions and I want to attach a content script to certain pages (as discussed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Modify_a_web_page ).

Problem is I don't want to specify the set of pages I want the content_script to run on in manifest.json when I write the extension but load it from local storage, i.e., I have an options page set up where the user can specify the pages the content script should be run on.  Is it possible to dynamically change the list of pages to be modified that is normally set using the content_script directive in manifest.json?

Thanks

Comment: You are asking two different questions here: "Can I dynamically change the URLs on which a *manifest.json* `content_script` is injected?" and "How can I inject content scripts on URLs which I dynamically determine?" While related, it would be much better if these were two separate Questions, not lumped into one Question. Please edit this Question down to one of those, and [ask a another Question for the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I took myself to be only asking the first question.  On rereading I see that it was unclear and changed it in the manner you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to modify the URLs into which injection will occur for a `manifest.json` `content_script` (either CSS or JavaScript).  The specified code will be injected in all matching URLs. This is for multiple reasons.

One of the reasons this is not possible is security/transparency to the user. The *manifest.json* explicitly declares which URLs your content script will be modifying, states that it will be modifying the active tab, or that it will have access all URLs/tabs. If you were permitted to change the URLs, then you would effectively be given the ability to access all URLs without explicitly declaring that you are doing so.

Yes, it would be possible to have a way to declare that you are going to do so. Chrome has an *experimental* way to do so with [`chrome.declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent). In Chrome this is considered experimental, even after being available for a couple/few years. It is not available in Firefox. When it will be available, or even if it will be available in Firefox is unclear. In addition, even in Chrome, it lacks some features available to other methods of injecting scripts (e.g. `run_at`/`runAt`).

In order to have complete control over injecting, or not injecting, you will need to perform the injection via [`tabs.insertCSS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS) and/or [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript). Injecting, or not injecting, scripts and CSS with these methods is fully under the control of the JavaScript in your extension. It is possible to get similar functionality using these methods to what you obtain with `manifest.json` `content_script` entries, but with more control. This greater control comes at the expense of greater complexity.

Answer (score 0):

How about that? There is a bunch of events to listen, you can pick any one which would satisfy uour requirements:

- onBeforeNavigate
- onCommitted
- onDOMContentLoaded
- onCompleted.

The documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation). And this is an example of how to make red background on subdomains of `example.com`. Of course, you can build the list of URL filters dynamically, this is just a PoC:

```
browser.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(
    function(details) {
        browser.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId, {code: 'body {background:red}'})
    },
    {url: [{hostSuffix: '.example.com'}]}
);
```

Comment: Choice of events really wouldn't help the use case I have in mind.  I wanted to create functionality (record comments posted to blogs) which would run on just those urls matching the patterns set by the user, i.e., if the user sets enable_record_comment: stackoverflow.com/* it would run on stackoverflow as well.  But I guess the answer is that if I want that kind of functionality I just have to eat any performance hit from running everywhere.

Comment: @PeterGerdes not sure what is the problem, event routing is done inside the browser and it should be pretty efficient. You can try to add listener with thousands of different filters - I didn't see any observable performance impact. When user changes the settings you can easily remove old listener and add the new one with updated filters set (second parameter of `addListener`)